# PHP: Having trouble passing a URL var

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have passed URL vars a million times, including on the current server I am using  For some reason I am having difficulty with no known server changes or upgrades.

URL:  http://www.thisismydomain.net/sched/mycalendar/2012/2

SCRIPT:  /sched/menu.php?currentYear=$1&currentWeek=$2

FYI the example URL works correctly: http://www.thisismydomain.net/sched/menu.php?currentYear=2012&currentWeek=2

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(thisismydomain\.net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sched/mycalendar/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /sched/menu.php?currentYear=$1&currentWeek=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Result:

*

> Not Found The requested URL /sched/mycalendar/2012/2 was not found on
>   this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

*

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Is .htaccess files enabled? I can't see any errors in the .htaccess but maybe AllowOverride is not properly configured.

Comment: it is enabled for other domains hosted on the server.  how do I check if it is enabled?

Comment: furthermore, I have placed .htaccess in both the /sched/ and the / parent server of where the domain points.. neither level works .. same 404 error

Comment: Test is htaccess is enabled by just putting some random text in the htaccess. If the server responds with a 500-error, that tells the htaccess is invalid, and so that means htaccess is enabled. PS. try adding `RewriteBase /`

Comment: I typed "cxzxvc" into my .htaccess and sure enough I get an error 500.  Can someone help me fix this problem?  I still have it with no solution.  Merry Christmas!

Comment: problem was mine: I placed the .htaccess in the incorrect folder.  silly me